# Mule-APIkit with baseUriParameter truncates resource path thus erroring out as 'resource not found'

Tags: parameters, base-url, mule-esb, apikit, raml-1.0

Can anyone please suggest/correct me here on how to get APIkit Router working with `baseUriParameter`. If the path in the HTTP Listener Connector is hardcoded like `/api/process/30001/*`, it all works fine. APIKit Router is able to route the requested resource path. But, when there is a placeholder in the HTTP Listener Connector path like `/api/process/{clientID}/*`, an error is thrown at APIkit Router as `No resource found`.

From the stacktrace below, I could see that the request resource path is truncated, for example, `/sample` becomes just `ple` and I couldn't find the reason why. Through debugging, I could see the complete request URI. [Image from debug mode to see the complete request path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpqmh.png).

I have tried a few other options like:

1. Checking 'keep raml base uri' in router config
2. Unchecking box 'parse Request' in *Advanced* tab of HTTP Listener Connector

I have checked through this, too, to be sure that my RAML conform with [raml-template-uris and uriparams](https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-08/raml-08.md#template-uris-and-uri-parameters).

I found this in the MuleSoft docs:

> In API Gateway Runtime 2.x and earlier, APIkit is designed to work very tightly with RAML interfaces, but does not automatically import the following items from the RAML definition:
>
> securitySchemes
>
> protocols
>
> baseUriParameters

So, how do I import `baseUriParameters`? How do I make it work?

I've been stuck with this issue for quite a long time, so any help is greatly appreciated. Please correct me if I missed something. Thanks a lot!

```
#%RAML 1.0
title: Test API
baseUri: /api/process/{clientID}
baseUriParameters: 
  clientID:
   type: number
   example: 300001
  
/sample:
  get:
    responses:
      200:
        body:
          application/json:
```

flow:

```
 <http:listener-config xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" name="baseuriprameter-apikit-httpListenerConfig" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration" />
<apikit:config xmlns:apikit="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/apikit" name="baseuriprameter-apikit-config" raml="baseuriprameter-apikit.raml" consoleEnabled="false" doc:name="Router" keepRamlBaseUri="false"/>
<flow name="baseuriprameter-apikit-main">
    <http:listener xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" config-ref="baseuriprameter-apikit-httpListenerConfig" path="/api/process/{clientID}/*" doc:name="HTTP" parseRequest="false"/>
    <apikit:router xmlns:apikit="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/apikit" config-ref="baseuriprameter-apikit-config" doc:name="APIkit Router"/>
    <exception-strategy ref="baseuriprameter-apikit-apiKitGlobalExceptionMapping" doc:name="Reference Exception Strategy"/>
</flow>
<flow name="baseuriprameter-apikit-console">
    <http:listener xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" config-ref="baseuriprameter-apikit-httpListenerConfig" path="/console/*" doc:name="HTTP" parseRequest="false"/>
    <apikit:console xmlns:apikit="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/apikit" config-ref="baseuriprameter-apikit-config" doc:name="APIkit Console"/>
</flow>
<flow name="get:/sample:baseuriprameter-apikit-config">
    <set-payload value="Hello World!" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
</flow>
```

stacktrace:

```
 WARN  2018-06-11 19:52:27,452 [[baseuriprameter-apikit].baseuriprameter- 
 apikit-httpListenerConfig.worker.01] org.mule.module.apikit.Configuration: 
No matching patterns for URI ple
ERROR 2018-06-11 19:52:28,082 [[baseuriprameter-apikit].baseuriprameter- 
apikit-httpListenerConfig.worker.01] 
org.mule.module.apikit.MappingExceptionListener: 

**************************************************
Message               : ple
Payload               : {NullPayload}
Payload Type          : org.mule.transport.NullPayload
Element               : /baseuriprameter-apikit-main/processors/0 @ 
baseuriprameter-apikit:baseuriprameter-apikit.xml:11 (APIkit Router)
Element XML           : <apikit:router 
xmlns:apikit="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/apikit" config- 
ref="baseuriprameter-apikit-config" doc:name="APIkit Router"> 
</apikit:router>
--------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.module.apikit.exception.NotFoundException: ple
atorg.mule.module.apikit.AbstractConfiguration$2.load(AbstractConfiguration.java:178)atorg.mule.module.apikit.AbstractConfiguration$2.load(AbstractConfiguration.java:169)
atcom.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3527)atcom.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2319)
atcom.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2282)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2197)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3937)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3941)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4824)
at org.mule.module.apikit.AbstractRouter.processRouterRequest(AbstractRouter.java:177)
at org.mule.module.apikit.AbstractRouter.processBlockingRequest(AbstractRouter.java:104)
at org.mule.module.apikit.AbstractRouter.processBlocking(AbstractRouter.java:98)
```

Comment: anybody ran into this issue and found any solution? 
thanks!

Comment: Which version of Mule Runtime are you using?